# How do I guarantee that a transaction is committed in MySQL before querying it?

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, locking

I have an application that is storing job state in a MySQL database (recently migrated from DynamoDB). I'm now running into the problem that an update is not visible for subsequent queries immediately, causing failures. This is the flow, completely sequential, no concurrency going on:

> 1. an object in db has state X
> 2. the object is updated to have state Y
> 3. the object is retrieved and is expected to have state Y
> 4. the retrieved object has state X, the task fails

From what I've learned, there seem to be two options to get around this:

1. Set isolation level to `serializable` in the update transaction.
2. Query using `select ... for update`, locking the row from updates.

I don't know enough to weigh the options though, maybe someone can help me sort this out.

For the db interface I'm using gorm in Go, no fancy custom sql or anything. Performance is not really an issue, the dataset is small and updates are relatively infrequent. The state field is indexed since it's frequently queried on.

Comment: MySQL query caching?

Comment: Could the update fail silently? Are you checking for errors properly? Whether this is all inside a transaction or not, what you describe should not happen...

Comment: The update is successful, and visible after some time, so the ugly hack until I have figured this out is just to wait 100ms. The update and the select are in different calls so separate transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with different transactions:

MySql-innodb-engine works with MVCC. That means as soon as you start a transaction its view to the database stays the same for the complete transaction. Even if parallel running transactions are completed and therefore no dirty read would be done, the changes will not be seen by the earlier started transaction.

If you keep this in mind, you might have an explanation for the weird behavior and can take deterministic actions to get around this.

Comment: I see, that makes sense, thanks. Do you have any suggestion how to address this?

Comment: if you need to look at state outside your current transactions possibly calling a bean-method with attribute "REQUIRES_NEW" can help. This will return information about completed transactions.  That works with Java and JTA, I don't know what kind of transactionsmanagement Go supports. if it works like jdbc, you can just create an extra connection to query using an extra transaction